# `-': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, implicit-conversion

A user inputs coins in a comma-separated list, and then they put a colon before the amount of change they want. We have coins: £1 (100p), 50p, 20p, 10p, 5p, 2p, and 1p, and we wish to give the customer 57p. The data input would be like this: `100,50,20,10,5,2,1:57`. Change is given to the user in the simplest way.

This is my code:

```
user_input = gets
i = 0
change_needed = 67  
coins = [50,5,20,1,5]
check_input = user_input.length
coins = user_input.split(',')
change_needed = user_input.split(':')
coins_length = coins.length
coins.map!(&:to_i)
coins = coins.sort {|a,b| b <=> a}
if check_input < 100 then
  while change_needed != 0 do
    if change_needed - coins[i] then
      change_needed -= coins[i]
    else
      i += 1
      puts "#{i} is the number in the coin array"
    end
  end
else
end
```

I get the following error message on the line `if change_needed - coins[i] then`:

> rb:17:in `-': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array (TypeError)

I don't understand this error message. It seems to be a simple fix, but I can't grasp what I need to do with my code to fix it.

Comment: Please provide explanation of your problem - what are `coins`, what is `change_needed` represent, what is expected input and output

Comment: Fixed, sorry though I had added that in there, here it is anyway: I'm trying to create a program where change is given to the user in the simplest way, the user inputs the coins in a comma-separated list, and then when they enter as many coins as they want, they put a colon before the amount of change given. We have the coins to the value of in: £1 (100p), 50p, 20p, 10p, 5p, 2p and 1p and we wish to give the customer 57p So the data input would be like this: 100,50,20,10,5,2,1:57

Comment: It's saying that something like ["123"] - 10 is not something that makes sense to ruby

Answer (score 1):

In `change_needed = user_input.split(':')` you are setting change_needed to an array, not to an int.

Try replacing:

```
coins = user_input.split(',')
change_needed = user_input.split(':')
```

with

```
coins_part, change_needed_part = user_input.split(':')
coins = coins_part.split(',')
change_needed = change_needed_part.to_i
```

Comment: So I would just need to do the .map! command again on the change_needed?

Comment: I don't think so. However, I cannot fully understand what you are trying to do: I suggest that you post an example for the user_input string.

Comment: I'm trying to create a program where change is given to the user in the simplest way, the user inputs the coins in a comma-separated list, and then when they enter as many coins as they want, they put a colon before the amount of change given.  We have the coins to the value of in: £1 (100p), 50p, 20p, 10p, 5p, 2p and 1p and we wish to give the customer 57p So the data input would be like this: 100,50,20,10,5,2,1:57

Comment: BTW, the are other errors in your code, but I will let you find them as part of your exercise ;-)